# Python - User input - start function automatically after entering 7 digits

Tags: python, tkinter

I am struggling to find the correct search terms to find an answer to my question. I have a program that is working, but I am trying to minimize the number of clicks required to make it work. I have a tkinter interface that takes a 7 digit input and looks it up in a spreadsheet and then displays some relevant information. Right now, the user scans a barcode which puts 7 digits in an entry box like this:

```
workorder = tk.Entry(root)
workorder.focus()
canvas1.create_window(175, 800, window=workorder)
```

Then, the user has to press the enter key to start the function that uses those 7 digits:

```
def f1(event):
    getPartNumber()
root.bind('<Return>', f1)
```

I am trying to find a way to start the function automatically so a keyboard is not required. I was trying to do something like:

```
if len(str(workorder)) == 7:
    getPartNumber()
```

However, it seems like this only works to check the length of an entry after the entry has been made. Is it possible to check on the state of the entry box before the entry is made?

Answer (score 1):

You can associate a variable with the entry widget, and then set a trace on the variable. The trace will call a function whenever the data in the widget changes. Inside the trace you can examine the length of the data and call a function when the length is 7.

Here's an example that updates a label when you enter 7 characters:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
label = tk.Label(root, text="", anchor="w")

entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
label.pack(side="top", fill="x")

def boom(*args):
    if len(var.get()) == 7:
        label.configure(text="Boom!")

var.trace("w", boom)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ah man, thank you Bryan! I got it working with this. I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough cred.